# Is there a problem with OpenID and Yahoo?

Tags: support, login, openid

Some SE sites are dropping Yahoo from the Log In With page, and it's listed below if you click "more ways" but the Yahoo button doesn't work.

I click it, an OpenID thing opens with "https://www.yahoo.com/" in it. Clicking Submit goes to a Yahoo page with an error.

Other SE sites that still list Yahoo in a rectangle alongside google and two others still work for me.

The site in question is Unix & Linux.

Comment: Something is going on on the Yahoo side - this has been happening on and off for a couple of weeks now. If you go http://openid.yahoo.com/ and login, you should be able to get an OpenId URL that you can simply paste into the URL field and use.

Comment: Ok thanks, will do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Yahoo OpenId service endpoints have been working intermittently for the last few weeks.

This is a problem on their side, not something we can fix on our end.

A work around is to visit the Yahoo openId site at:

https://openid.yahoo.com

Then log in, click the "Get Started" button and looking at the openId URLs that are offered

These have the form `https://me.yahoo.com/<some identifier>`

This can be pasted into the "manually enter your openId" field and will log you in.

Comment: doesn't work. I lost my account and had to sign up using Google.

Comment: @user258505 - the account is not lost, though Yahoo logins seem to have been broken on their side (possibly a side effect of their fixing their heartbleed vulnerability). You can sign up for a Stack Exchange open Id using your Yahoo email address and get an account with that openId - this can be merged with your existing account (as both will have the same email address).