# Cannot log in on data.stackexchange.com with Yahoo! anymore

Tags: bug, login, data-explorer

1. Opened https://data.stackexchange.com/account/login
2. Clicked **Yahoo!** image
3. Getting the following message:

> This message has already been processed. This could indicate a replay attack in progress.

> [image]

Bug?

Comment: Yahoo's OpenID implementation has been causing problems on and off all over Stack Exchange. If there is a bug, it is on their side.

Comment: See [Is Yahoo OpenID login broken?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239635) for the most recent example.

Comment: More examples: [Cannot log in to SO or any Stack Exchange site using Yahoo OpenID on mobile devices](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/224498), [Is there a problem with OpenID and Yahoo?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/223576), [Stack Overflow login via Yahoo! is broken](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/221313), [Yahoo Sign-In Option appears to be broken](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/220430), etc.

Comment: If you want something that works, add another login and use it. From my little experience with Yahoo!, they are the worst I've seen.

Comment: However this error message seems to come from `DotNetOpenId` library: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/2240748/1420197 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/727838/1420197. I agree with @ShadowWizard that Yahoo! is not the best choice, but connecting with Google, probably I will create another account, or? I want to access my account that was created using Yahoo! credentials.

Comment: Whoops, SEDE is indeed different, you can't link logins in there. Sorry!

Comment: @ShadowWizard Exactly. That's my problem...

Comment: For the time being, use the changed URL for the Yahoo open Id provider: https://me.yahoo.com - you should be able to use your own login with this URL. We _are_ changing it across the board.

Comment: It worked. Thanks, @Oded!